# Congruence, $p$-adic valuation, Quadratic residue, divisibility, basic diophantine equations (Pell, Pythagorean triple) , Bezout what's next?

Tags: number-theory

I really enjoy number-theory. I read a lot of PDF on the internet on this field.

Here is what I know on number theory :

- divisibility
- basic diophantine equations (Pell, Pythagorean triple)
- Bezout theorem
- Congruence
- $p$-adic valuation
- Quadratic residue
- Chinese remainder theorem

These are the basics "things" in number theory yet I would like to learn more in number theory, that's why I am just asking :

What theorems, or nice results should I study in number theory ?

Comment: If you haven't taken up a course on number theory and just read it on your own, I would suggest you to look at problems. Number Theory is a field filled with notorious problems. Math is not Physics, just knowing the theorems aren't enough. Try a few problems, and test your understanding. (Not the straightforward calculation problems) You will find that you will need to understand all the proofs, motivations, etc. thoroughly to make any progress at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! That's definitely true, but this is actually what I do. I looked at tons of olympiad problems !

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you for your answer ! I am going to look at all of these things. What is the best to begin ?

Comment: Best to start is with the book of Ireland and Rosen, on an introduction to number theory. Look at the syllabus.

Comment: Not knowing a lot more than you I think. I agree though that the proof methods are worth comprehending to full (If it's a good Author). And do a little algebra if not just to see most if not all, again where you did not expect

Comment: @DietrichBurde This is what I am looking for. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 3):

A good book introducing number theory usually covers many nice results. The table of contents, for example, for the book [A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4757-1779-2) by Ireland and Rosen is

$\bullet$ Unique Factorization

$\bullet$ Applications of Unique Factorization

$\bullet$ Congruence

$\bullet$ The Structure of $U(ℤ/nℤ)$

$\bullet$ Quadratic Reciprocity

$\bullet$ Quadratic Gauss Sums

$\bullet$ Finite Fields

$\bullet$ Gauss and Jacobi Sums

$\bullet$ Cubic and Biquadratic Reciprocity

$\bullet$ Equations over Finite Fields

$\bullet$ The Zeta Function

$\bullet$ Algebraic Number Theory

$\bullet$ Quadratic and Cyclotomic Fields

$\bullet$ The Stickelberger Relation and the Eisenstein Reciprocity Law

$\bullet$ Bernoulli Numbers

$\bullet$ Dirichlet $L$-functions

$\bullet$ Diophantine Equations

$\bullet$ Elliptic Curves

Comment: But if PID is process ID (As it was for me) then first get a tad of basic algebra prior